# SQL Server - Partitioning a Table by Day of Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

I am new to partitioning so I have been reading up on it trying to understand it and how to implement it. We have a table that we expect to get very big so it was recommended by the DBA that we partition it. It was decided that we would partition the table by day of the month. So I created files and file groups for each day of the month. Then I ran the following script to create the partition function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfPartitionFunction (INT)
AS
RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)
```

Then I ran the following script to create the partition scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME psPartitionScheme
AS
PARTITION pfPartitionFunction TO (FG1, FG2, FG3, FG4, FG5, FG6, FG7, FG8, FG9, FG10, FG11, FG12, FG13, FG14, FG15, FG16, FG17, FG18, FG19, FG20, FG21, FG22, FG23, FG24, FG25, FG26, FG27, FG28, FG29, FG30, FG31, [PRIMARY])
```

Then I attempted to create the table with a computed column that will hold the day of month for the created date column, and will also serve as the partition column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartitionedTable](
    [Id] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDay] AS DAY(CreatedDate) PERSISTED,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON psPartitionScheme([CreatedDay])
) ON psPartitionScheme([CreatedDay])
```

But I got the following error message: "Column 'CreatedDay' is partitioning column of the index 'PK_ID'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key." I can't include the computed column as part of the primary key as we must ensure that the IDs are unique. So I specified [PRIMARY] for the primary key instead of psPartitionScheme. When I ran that I got the following message: "The filegroup 'PRIMARY' specified for the clustered index 'PK_ID' was used for table 'dbo.PartitionedTable' even though partition scheme 'psPartitionScheme' is specified for it." When I run the following query to check the partitions:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.partitions
WHERE OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = 'PartitionedTable'
```

I see only one partition:
[image]

I also have two other indices on the table. When I create those table indices on the partition scheme, I see 31 partitions for each in the sys.partitions table. So that seems to work. But because the table is not partitioned, I am not able to take advantage of partition switching, which is another requirement for this table. When I run the partition switch script:

```
ALTER TABLE PartitionedTable
SWITCH PARTITION 3
TO PartitionedTableArchive PARTITION 3
```

I get the following warning: "The specified partition 3 for the table 'MyDatabase.dbo.PartitionedTable' was ignored in ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement because the table is not partitioned."

And I also get the following error: "'ALTER TABLE SWITCH' statement failed. The index 'IX' is partitioned while table 'MyDatabase.dbo.PartitionedTable' is not partitioned."

Is there anything else I can do to partition the table correctly without including the computed column as part of the primary key?

Comment: Partitioning a table by day of month, assuming you're going to have more than one month, is a strange approach, because it practically ensures you will never be able to switch out partitions for maintenance, and at best it reduces the total size per partition by a factor 30 -- not exactly an order of magnitude. Typically you would partition by calendar month (or, if your data is truly humongous, you might consider partitioning by calendar day). Did your DBA actually recommend this scheme? I have a hard time imagining when such a thing would come in handier than partitioning chronologically.

Comment: The more I think about it the weirder it gets, really! Even queries over the partitioned data would be hard to optimize, because even (e.g.) a query that ranged over a single day would cause a scan of all partitions, unless you took pains to calculate the day and include it as a filter in your query. Double check with your DBA if they said "you should partition it" because they've heard about partitioning and think it's cool, or because they actually have experience with partitioning on a real table (of at least 100M rows, if possible...)

Comment: The fact that this table has, as its primary key, an `ID` column of type `VARCHAR(255)` also throws up a red flag with me -- `VARCHAR(255)` is the kind of "I don't know, just make it able to hold anything and give it a round power of two size even though that does nothing" type that sounds like exactly the sort of thing you *don't* want your clustered index to be on. Is it actually going to be a sequential number? A GUID? A completely random string? This doesn't matter much for "simple" tables with a few rows; it matters a lot when you've got a table so big you're considering partitioning it.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful comments. I'm not sure if the DBA has experience partitioning tables. My understanding is that they suggested it and then left it to us to actually do it without any guidance. I came on the project after decisions had been made, so I'm not sure who recommended the scheme. I see your point about the inability to switch partitions using this scheme. I hadn't realized that. Why would a query that ranged over a single day cause a scan of all partitions?

Comment: Because SQL Server cannot optimize a query of the form `WHERE d >= '20190326' AND d < '20190327'` for partition elimination if the table isn't actually partitioned by `d`. It would need to see that that date can only exist in partition 26, and the engine simply isn't smart enough for that -- you would need to manually add `and day = 26`. With proper indexing, those superfluous scans would not actually take much time (it would quickly see that date range is empty in the other 29 partitions) but it would still be a waste. Partition elimination is a great thing when it works.

Comment: As far as the primary key is concerned, the table will be populated with data from an external vendor. From what I can tell it looks like the ID coming from the vendor is a GUID. I will clarify with the vendor and see if we could update the type for that column.

Comment: If it is a GUID (as in, not a sequentially increasing value), it's a classic case of something you don't want as your clustered index because it will cause index fragmentation. You can have still have it as your (non-clustered) primary key, but then cluster on a `BIGINT` identity that you don't use for anything else, or (better yet) actually cluster on the chronological `CreatedDate`. Getting this right is possibly more important than partitioning. (Source: I maintain a database that has a partitioned table much like this, currently at 9.5 B rows and counting.)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of data. Thank you for the information, very helpful. So I have a question. Let's say we choose to partition on the calendar day. Would a query that searches only by the ID column have to scan all partitions?

Comment: Assuming the ID index is aligned with the table, yes. Consider the partitions as if they were separate tables that are joined together in a view with a `UNION ALL` (because that's sort of how it actually works). To find a row with a particular ID, the 30 partitions (30 index pieces) need to be accessed separately to see if the ID is there. These will be 30 index seeks, however, and index seeks being what they are, you usually don't notice if you're doing 30 as opposed to 1. If the index is not aligned, it's just one big index, so one seek (but then no benefits from partitions).

Comment: Excellent information. Thank you very much.